I want to pass multiple parameters to Python functions
I am using wkhtmltopdf with Python by calling Python from within the classic asp.
I defined some parameters as default in wkhtmltopdf. with the name "option".
But later, when I call the function, I want to be able to change the page-size and cookie values, and I want the other default values to remain the same.
My code.py file:
    def htmlToPdf(self, html_file, pdf_file, additional_options=None):
        path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
        
        option = {
            'quiet': True,
            'page-size': 'A4', 
            'cookie':[('login', 'token1=7040D304-34A5-444F-A10D-6942ABEC9B9F&token2=6E8405C7-B6BE-41F6-A5D3-0A20574A6849')],
            'margin-top': '0.0in',  
            'margin-right': '0.0in', 
            'margin-bottom': '0.0in', 
            'margin-left': '0.0in', 
        }

        if additional_options:
            option.update(additional_options)
        
        print(option)

The way I call the function:
result = htmlToPdf(html_file, r'c:\Web\Pdf1.pdf',additional_options={'page-size':'A3','cookie': [('login', 'token1=1111111-34A5-444F-A10D-6942ABEC9B9F&token2=222222-B6BE-41F6-A5D3-0A20574A6849')]})
print(result)


The error it gives:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\PythonAsp\code.py", line 19, in 
result=htmlToPdf(html_file, r'c:\print\Pdf1.pdf',additional_options={'page-size':'A3','cookie': [('login', 'token1=111111-34A5-444F-A10D-6942ABEC9B9F&token2=222222-B6BE-41F6-A5D3-0A20574A6849')]})
TypeError: htmlToPdf() got an unexpected keyword argument 'additional_options'

I tried giving page-size and cookie values separately. I can give the page-size separately, but I still get stuck in the cookie and it does not accept strings.
I can have more than one cookie value.

Just pointing out that wkhtmltopdf is no longer maintained: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html

@oBrstisf8o I couldn't find an alternative that works with win32com.server.register , cookies, css and javascript support.

What about Puppeteer? The only downside I see is that there isn't any maintained python port of it (it runs on node.js - using it requires javascript), but it seems like it is capable of converting html to PDF, but I never used it, so I can't help much there.
